# Alterar título da Action Bar com Tab Bar

Tags: android, mobile, actionbar

Tenho 3 Tab Bars que ficam no rodapé do layout e a action bar no topo, como padrão. Preciso saber como modificar o título da minha Action Bar toda vez que uma Tab Bar diferente for selecionada. Grato.

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa fazer o SetTitle() na ActionBar toda vez que mudar de Activity.
Pode usar pegar o titulo direto da Activity

`getActionBar().setTitle(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName());`

Ou você pode colocar um titulo que customizado direto do arquivo de Strings.

```
getActionBar().setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.sua_string));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use isso sempre que uma Activity for inciada.

```
Actionbar actionbar = getActionbar();

//Ou

Actionbar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();

actionbar.setTitle("Digite ou chame seu titulo aqui");
```